how to update the values of other model property value without changing the value of specific property(which only accept unique values)
I am building a simple project in Razor Page using .NET 6. I am new to asp.net core. i have a model 'Class' with property 'RollNo' Model property which only accepts unique value. unique attribute validation
The problem is when I try to update the values of other property without changing the current value of 'RollNo', it obviously doesn't allow me to do so with a validation error

Roll number already exists

because the current value of 'RollNo' already exist in SQL Server.
So my question: how do I update rest of the model property without changing the value of property that only accepts unique value?
Excuse my way of asking question as I am new here and currently don't have enough experience. Also thanks in advance.

Please don't post code as image.

You need to customize your edit logic too, modify the state. Follow my sample please.
UniqueRollNoAttribute.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using UniqueTest.Data;
using UniqueTest.Models;

namespace UniqueTest
{
    public class UniqueRollNoAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var dbContext = (UniqueTestContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(UniqueTestContext));
            var classInstance = (TestModel1)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            // Get the current RollNo value from the database
            var existingClass = dbContext.TestModel1
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.RollNo == (int)value);

            if (existingClass != null && existingClass.Id != classInstance.Id)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Roll number already exists");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}

Edit.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using UniqueTest.Data;
using UniqueTest.Models;

namespace UniqueTest.Pages.TestModel1s
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UniqueTestContext _context;

        public EditModel(UniqueTestContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public TestModel1 TestModel1 { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            TestModel1 = await _context.TestModel1.FindAsync(id);

            if (TestModel1 == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            // Detach the original entity if it's being tracked
            _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();

            var existingClass = await _context.TestModel1.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == TestModel1.Id);

            if (existingClass == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Check if RollNo has changed
            if (existingClass.RollNo != TestModel1.RollNo)
            {
                var rollNoExists = await _context.TestModel1.AnyAsync(c => c.RollNo == TestModel1.RollNo);
                if (rollNoExists)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Class.RollNo", "Roll number already exists");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            _context.Entry(TestModel1).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClassExists(TestModel1.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        private bool ClassExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.TestModel1.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}



Successfully modified.
